# Correspondence between line bundles and $U(1)$-bundles: a mistake from the physicists?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, fiber-bundles

I am reading a paper written by physicists and they say the following:

> Let $(L,h,\nabla)$ be an holomorphic line bundle equipped with a Hermitian metric $h$ and Chern connection $\nabla$. If $e^{f_{ab}}$ are the transition functions of $L$ on the non-empty overlapping of two open sets $U_{a}$ and $U_{b}$, then the transition functions in the associated $U(1)$-bundle $\mathcal{U}$ are $e^{iIm(f_{ab})}$.
>
> In addition, let $\theta$ be the local one-form connection of $\nabla$ on a local trivialization of $L$. Then corresponding connection on the $U(1)$-bundle $\mathcal{U}$ is $Im(\theta) = -\frac{i}{2}(\theta - \bar{\theta})$. Then, the covariant derivative of any section $\Psi\in\Gamma(\mathcal{U})$ is $d\Psi + Im(\theta)\Psi$.

My question is: is this correct? Because I cannot make sense of it.

Comment: What's wrong? The transition functions of $\mathcal{U}$ are in $U(1)$. This is an usual thing in quantum stuff, you exponentiate self-adjoint operators to get an unitary representation. About the connection, you just have to check that the connection in $L$ is given by $d + \theta$, hence the induced connection in $\mathcal{U}$ will be $d + Im (\theta)$.

Comment: @user40276: thanks. Since sections of the line bundle $L$ are associated to equivariant functions on $\mathcal{U}$, rather than sections of $\mathcal{U}$, I didn't expect the induced connection in $\mathcal{U}$ to act on sections of $\mathcal{U}$. In fact, how is $d\Psi$ defined when $\Psi$ is a section of a principal bundle? $d$ is well defined acting on forms, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @user40276: as far as I know, expressions of the form $d\Psi +Im(\theta)\Psi$ do not make sense on sections of a principal bundle but on sections of a vector bundle. In fact, a connection on a principal bundle induces such covariant derivative on the space of sections of the associated vector bundle. In fact, the object $d + Im(\theta)$ looks like is not well defined acting on sections of a principal bundle.

Comment: This is a general fact. Every connection can be written as $\nabla = d + A$ where $A$ is a matrix of one-forms. Furthermore, $d$ is defined on sections locally by the usual differentiation on manifolds.

Comment: I agree that a connection $\nabla\colon \Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(E\otimes T^{\ast}M)$ on a vector bundle $E\to M$ can be locally written as you say by using a local frame. But that does not solve the question, since that is not the local form of a connection on a principal bundle, which anyway does NOT act on sections of the principal bundle but on equivariant functions on it, since equivariant functions correspond to sections on the associated vector bundle.

Comment: @user40276: you say "Furthermore, $d$ is defined on sections locally by the usual differentiation on manifolds." This does not makes sense for principal bundles, which is what I am asking and the reason of my question. What you say is OK for vector bundles, and indeed that is part of the exterior covariant derivative $d_{\nabla}\colon \Omega^{k}(M,E)\to \Omega^{k+1}(M,E)$ when locally written. But for principal bundles the same characterization does not work.

Comment: You're right. The analogous of $\nabla s$ for principal bundles is $s^{*} \omega$ where $\omega$ is a connection form. Actually there's a convention in YM-theory, see http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahjde/YM-lectures/lecture3.pdf

Comment: You have to consider the embedding $U(1) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and differentiate as in the case of a line bundle.

Comment: @user40276: could you elaborate on your last comment? Thanks.

Comment: Let $e^{i Im (\theta)}$ be a section of $\mathcal{U}$, where $\theta $ is a section of $L$. Then define $d (e^{iIm(\theta)}) = id \theta$

Comment: @user40276: I cannot make sense of what you say. In fact $d\theta$ is not well defined in $L$ either, that is only part of the exterior covariant derivative when locally written using a local frame in $L$. Thanks anyway, let us wait if an expert in the subject respond.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are claiming. Every connection can be written as $\nabla = d + A$, where $\nabla s = ds + s^{*} A$ for a section $s : U \rightarrow G$, where $G$ is a Lie group and $A \in \Omega^1 (P, \mathfrak{g})$. $ds$ is simply the differentiation of functions on manifolds.

Comment: @user40276: you are mistaken various related concepts about connections in principal bundles and the induced connection on a vector bundle, but this is not the place to discuss this. I will wait for an expert in the topic to respond to my question.

Comment: $d\theta$ in well-defined in $L$, otherwise you'e contradicting yourself, since $L$ is a line bundle.

Comment: @user40276 The object "$d\theta$", where $\theta$ is a section of $L$, is not well defined. The de Rahm differential $d$ is defined acting on forms, not sections. What is well defined is the exterior covariant derivative $d_{\nabla}$. When written locally, $d_{\nabla}$ contains a piece with $d$, but this obviously does not imply that $d$ is well defined on sections. Anyway, as I said, this is not the place to discuss this, if you have any doubts pose a question yourself.

Comment: No it's well define on sections. See any differential geometry book. A section is locally $s = s_i e_i$ for a basis $e_i$ and $ds = ds_i \otimes e_i$.

Comment: A connection on a vector bundle is always of the form $d+ A$ where $A$ is a matrix of one forms. Just subtract two connections and compute it. For principal bundles, the associated bundle has a connection $d+ A$ where $A = \rho_{*} \omega$, $\rho$ is a representation of $G$ and $\omega$  one-form connection.

Comment: @user40276: make a change of frame and check if the definition that you wrote depends on the frame used. If it depends on the frame then it is not well defined. You will see that what you wrote indeed depends on the frame unless the bundle is flat, because only in that case $d_{\nabla} = d$. But in general $d$ is not well defined acting on sections of a vector bundle. Again, this is not the place to discuss this. If you have any doubts you can pose your own question. For a reference you can read: "Differential geometry of complex vector bundles" by Kobayashi.

Comment: Yes, of course. $d^2 = 0$, hence the bundle is flat. I don't see your point. $d + A$ is well defined, $d$ is simply a notation.